# How to separate and transpose row in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have excel sheet with two columns, the first column contains contain names and second contain multiple semicolons separated values I want to separate the second column and transpose with first column value repeated,

example
sheet:

```
testa   KRAS;EGFR
second  HSP90AB1;KSR1;PLXND1;LAMB2;ROCK2
test    PPP2R1A;TRIB3;EGFR;FGFR2
```

Result:

```
testa   KRAS
testa   EGFR
second  HSP90AB1
second  KSR1
second  PLXND1
second  LAMB2
second  ROCK2
test    PPP2R1A
test    TRIB3
test    EGFR
test    FGFR2
```

Right now I am manually separating it, is there any macros/VBA for this?

Comment: "provide macros/VBA" Unfortunately this is not a "Code For Me" site. We can help you address specific issues in your code to overcome obstacles or errors, but we generally don't write code from scratch for free.  If you have something that you have tried, please edit your post to include your attempt.

Comment: If you are looking for how to get started, look into the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function, and you will also need to learn how to loop.  Simple looping examples [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Comment: You can also use the function "Text to Columns" to separate the second column, then copy and Paste Special - Transpose and then just fill in the first column by copying or dragging. Repeat ad nauseum.

Comment: @nbayly I tried that but I have like 800 rows to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to have a macro that pretty much does this, so I just tweaked it to match your data.  Otherwise, I'd also ask that you show some effort first.  I assume your data is in column A ("testa", "second", etc) and column B (the delimited data)

```
Sub splitCopyDown()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim cols As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long, k As Long

Set rng = Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), Semicolon:=True

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    cols = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, cols))
    Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(cols - 2, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
    rng.Copy
    rng.Cells(1).Offset(1, -1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    rng.Clear
Next i

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value
End Sub
```

(It's an older macro, but it checks out. You could likely make it more efficient)

Answer (score 0):

While BruceWayne beat me to the punch, I quickly jotted this subroutine out so I figured I should share it so I don't feel like I wasted 5 minutes of my day.

```
Sub liftAndSeperate()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim intWriteRow As Integer
    Dim rngReadRow As Range
    Dim readArrayElem As Variant

    'Assuming the data is in Sheet1 A1:B20
    Set rngData = Sheet1.Range("A1:B20")

    'Assuming we will write to Sheet2 starting at row 1:
    intWriteRow = 1

    'Loop through each row in that range:
    'The row we are reading will be held in variable rngReadRow
    For Each rngReadRow In rngData.Rows

        'Generate an array using split and loop through the array to write the values out
        For Each readArrayElem In Split(rngReadRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, ";")

            'Write out column A from sheet1 to sheet2
            Sheet2.Cells(intWriteRow, 1).Value = rngReadRow.Cells(1, 1)

            'Write out the array element
            Sheet2.Cells(intWriteRow, 2).Value = readArrayElem

            'Increment to the next write row
            intWriteRow = intWriteRow + 1
        Next readArrayElem
    Next rngReadRow
End Sub
```

p.s. BruceWayne is Batman (now his cover is blown)

Comment: (I wonder, can we edit posts to remove 100% absolutely and completely false and irrelevant information? I have no idea what you mean with that last sentence....hmmmmmmm.)